# AVCaptureMovieFileOutput crash on iPhone 5S

Tags: iphone, avfoundation, avcapturemoviefileoutput

My app is crashing on iPhone 5S and not on any other device and its pointing to an exception raised in startRecordingToOutputFileURL:recordingDelegate :

```
   Date/Time:           2013-11-01 13:18:03.672 -0400
   OS Version:          iOS 7.0.3 (11B511)
   Report Version:      104

   Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
   Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
   Triggered by Thread:  0

    Last Exception Backtrace:
    0   CoreFoundation                  0x2f164e83 __exceptionPreprocess + 131
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x394c56c7 objc_exception_throw + 38
    2   AVFoundation                    0x2e0679b9 -[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:recordingDelegate:] + 512
```

I don't have an iPhone 5S to test and wouldn't want to get a one just for this purpose. And I made checks for obvious errors like nil file URL, nil delegate, and none of them is hit.

How do I debug this, any ideas ? Is there a possibility to do a remote testing and extract logs from a beta tester's device ? I checked that most of the log extracts apps are not working on iOS 7.

EDIT : I strongly suspect its got to do with the way I setup AVCaptureDevice. Here is my code, please point if I am doing it correctly or not.

Here is how I setup the device input.

```
    AVCaptureDeviceFormat *bestFormat = nil;

    CMVideoDimensions bestDimensions = {0.f, 0.f};
    CMVideoDimensions dimensions;

    NSInteger width = [self videoTrackWidth];
    NSInteger height = [self videoTrackHeight];

    NSInteger fps = [[self currentFPSFromSettings] integerValue];

    if (fps > 30) {
        [self configureCameraForHighFrameRate:device]; //No crash if this path is executed
    } else {
    /* crashes only if this path is executed */
        for ( AVCaptureDeviceFormat *format in [device formats] ) {
            CMFormatDescriptionRef formatDesc = [format formatDescription];
            dimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(formatDesc);

            if (dimensions.width >= width && dimensions.height >= height) {
                for ( AVFrameRateRange *range in format.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges ) {
                    if (range.maxFrameRate >= fps) {
                        bestDimensions = dimensions;
                        bestFormat = format;
                        MPLog(@" -- Max FPS = %f", range.maxFrameRate);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (!bestFormat) {
            bestFormat = [[device formats] lastObject];
        }

        if ( bestFormat ) {
            if ( [device lockForConfiguration:NULL] == YES ) {
                device.activeFormat = bestFormat;
                MPLog(@"Device Max Zoom = %f", bestFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor);
                self.maxZoomSupportedByDevice = bestFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor;
                [device unlockForConfiguration];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: add a breakpoints and tell us where does your app crashes?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an iPhone 5S to test and its only users who are telling me. As a side note, I observe that the way I setup the AVCaptureDeviceInput and add it to MovieFileOutput could be the culprit.

Comment: Get crash logs from your testers and symbolicate them in Xcode organizer. http://bjango.com/help/crashlog/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My app was crashing on the iPhone 5s when creating AVCaptureSession. 
Checking my build in iTunes Connect I discovered that it only have armv7 under Supported Architectures. 
Probably when I first created the archive I had my iPhone 5c connected to Xcode but creating it again without my phone attached creates a new build with both armv7 and arm64 support. 
Now the same code works on the iPhone 5s.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually it was found that there was an issue in the method of manually configuring AVCaptureSession as outlined in the source code in the question. In the code, I was trying to find AVCaptureDeviceFormat that supports 30 fps & has the highest possible visual dimensions. I was assuming the highest dimensions that any format could support 30 fps is 1920x1080, but iPhone 5s was the first device that supported full 8 Mega pixel sample buffers @30 fps. And AVCaptureMovieFileOutput could not work with 8 MP sample buffers for encoding and crashed !